# Resposta de WebApi personalisada

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

Olá,
Tenho um serviço de WebApi e gostaria de obter uma resposta especificamente com uma Data, mas na hora que eu chamo esse serviço e recebo o retorno do meu PostAsync o que vejo é apenas um httpResult dizendo que foi OK.

chamada ao WebApi 
var result = await client.PostAsync(URI, content);

Retorno do metodo na web api
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataTeste);

O que quer que eu mande no retorno, eu não recebo ...

Tentei alterar o tipo de retorno do método para DateTime, ou string mas também não deu certo.
Atualmente ele é um HttpResponseMessage m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é algo assim que você precisa:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]DateTime newDate)
 {
      return Ok<DateTime>(newDate);
 }
```

O método `OK<T>()` está dentro da classe `ApiController` utilizada como base da sua WebApi e já é responsável por serializar o parâmetro.

Para ler o conteúdo no C# você deve seguir assim:

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{               
    var requestBody = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = url,
        Content = new StringContent(body)
    };
    requestBody.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") { CharSet = "UTF-8" };

    var httpResult = http.SendAsync(requestBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var resultContent = httpResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var resultStatus = (httpResult.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    DateTime? myDate;
    if (resultStatus)
        myDate= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(resultContent, JSettings);
    else
        myDate= null;
}
```

Abs.

Comment: Mas dentro do result da minha chamada a API eu continuei não achando a data. 
A data estaria serializada na propriedade Header?
Como eu poderia pegar o retorno?

var result = await client.PostAsync(URI, content);

Comment: Complementei minha resposta com o método de como ler o retorno no C#. Veja se te atende.